# How to setup Tooling Api in Java Application?

Tags: api, java, tooling-api, wsdl

I am developing a Java application that should be able to connect to **any** Salesforce org and use the Tooling Api.

Salesforce provides a WSDL but as I understand it is org specific, correct ?

Could someone please explain how to approach this problem ?

Appreciate your help,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the Enterprise API is Org specific.

The Tooling API will work with any org providing the user has API access. In addition to API access the user making the API calls may require [additional permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_overview.htm), such as "View All Data" to query Tooling API objects.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. So I can use the objects configured in the WSDL after I login to SF using WSC or any other login flow ? Correct ?

Comment: Assuming the user who is logged in has the required permissions, then yes. Like the Partner API, the Tooling API should be Metadata driven. It will adjust what it exposes to the user based on their level of access.